# chart.js show time in series

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to show the x values of a array as time stamp. The x value was generated by x = Date.now()

```
var test = {
    "datasets": [{
        "data": [{
            "x": 1609753734252,
            "y": 44.82420388241937
        }, {
            "x": 1609753735263,
            "y": 46.02068615892796
        }, {
            "x": 1609753741254,
            "y": 53.21622091958411
        }]
    }, {
        "data": [{
            "x": 1609753734252,
            "y": 129.77634259930292
        }, {
            "x": 1609753735263,
            "y": 129.86789675071483
        }, {
            "x": 1609753741254,
            "y": 129.9137373479274
        }]
    },
    "labels": [1609753734252, 1609753735263, 1609753741254]
}
```

The options

```
    var config = {
        type: 'line',
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            responsiveAnimatinDuration: 500,
            animation: {
                duration: 0
            },
            elements: {
                point: {
                    radius: 0
                },
                line: {
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    fill : false
                }
            },
            legend : {
                display : false
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type : 'time',
                    time : {
                        format : "HH:MM",
                        unit : "hour"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    };
```

The javascript code:

```
    config.data = test; 
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx.getContext('2d'), config);
```

I want to show the time in format hh:mm? What is wrong?

The data will be updated all 500 ms. Can I hide the transitions?

Comment: Why don't you format the date in `Date.now()`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have that option format as you're using it

You can use the [unit](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-units) and the [parser](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#parser), this last one accepts the same format options as moment accepts.

You can try using as a string like the following:

> MM-DD-YYYY

Or sending a function, like this

```
parser: (tickValue) => { 
  // just as an example
  if (tickValue > 0) 
    return moment(tickValue).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following way mentioned here in the documentation to formate date
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats.

I tried it with the following:

```
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        displayFormats: {
                            second: 'hh:mm:ss'
                        }
                        // unit : 'minute'
                    }
                }]
```

Now I get all the years from 1971 to today. But I want to have the x-scaling set auto. Without displayFormat all times are displayed. But unfortunately as long int.

I also tried it with "unit". After that I get an exception: isAMomemtObject

Comment: I tried it with the following:
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        displayFormats: {
                            second: 'hh:mm:ss'
                        }
                        // unit : 'minute'

                    }
                }]